# Hive extract text before <br>

Tags: java, regex, hive

In Apache hive how can i extract the substring from a given string.
I have a column containing the below value.

I need to extract ABC3170 from the below string i.e till `<br>`

my data looks some what like below. I want to get all the records and eliminate text after `<BR>`
**Col1**
`---------`
G3333 
XYZD20 
5289 
ABC2620 
CDF-B700S 
CUSTOM MANAGER 
ABC3170 `<BR></DIV><DIV DIR="AUTO" STYLE="DIRECTION: LTR; MARGIN: 0; PADDING: 0; FONT-FAMILY: SANS-SE`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Regexp_Extract](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) function and matching java regex to extract the value before `<BR>.`

***Regex Expression:***

```
(.*?)\\s+<BR> //capture without space until <BR>
```

***Hive Query:***

```
hive> select regexp_extract(<column.name>,"(.*?)\\s+<BR>",1) from <db.name>.<tab.name>;
```

**Example:**

```
hive> select regexp_extract(txt,"(.*?)\\s+<BR>",1),txt from i;
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
|   _c0    |                                                                     txt                                                                     |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| ABC3170  | ABC3170 <BR></DIV><DIV DIR="AUTO" STYLE="DIRECTION: LTR; MARGIN: 0; PADDING: 0; FONT-FAMILY: SANS-SERIF; FONT-SIZE: 11PT; COLOR: BLACK; ">  |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have updated the question with more data.Please let me know how to get all the records except <BR.